# Best graphics driver for HP Laptop with Switchable Graphics?

Tags: ati, gpu

I'm planning to dual boot my laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. I'm using an HP Pavilion DV6-6140tx laptop, which is packed with AMD 6770M 1GB GPU. For windows, I'm using a third party AMD CCC driver and it works like charm and GPU switching happens butter smooth. I just want to know where I can find the best driver for Ubuntu(for my laptop) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.10 now supports Hybrid Graphics. If you have Ubuntu 13.10 and Radeon hybrid graphics you can install the driver and catalyst control center as easy as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

You can start catalyst control center in dash by shortcut or through terminal as follows:

```
sudo amdccle
```

PS:-
  Remember to run Catalyst Control Center as root to switch graphics. Unlike in Windows, you need to restart the system to complete switching.

Comment: For me the catalyst control centre command is "sudo amdcccle".